# Wrap a console.log with infinite optional params

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a custom logger which just wraps a `console.log` but always adds something to the start which makes it absolutely clear that the log is coming from my plugin.

I have come up with the following code:

```
var log = function(param1, param2) {
    if (typeof param3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('[MyPlugin]', param1, param2, param3);
    } else if (typeof param2 !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('[MyPlugin]', param1, param2);
    }
};
```

This allows the developer to run the following:

```
log('foo', 'bar');
// Outputs '[MyPlugin] foo bar'

log('foo');
// Outputs '[MyPlugin] foo'
```

But I hope that this can be improved upon.

The issues with this implementation are:

1. The logging function only allows two parameters. It would be better if it could accept many.
2. There's lots of repetition (multiple `console.log` calls).

**What I have tried.**

I thought maybe the [ES6 spread-operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) would work:

```
var log = function(...params) {
    console.log('[MyPlugin]', params);
};
```

Which allows the developer to run:

```
log('foo', 'bar');
// Outputs '[MyPlugin] Array [ "foo", "bar" ]'

log('foo');
// Outputs '[MyPlugin] Array [ "foo" ]'
```

You can see that the output is not the same as in the original function.

*Is there a better solution?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spread notation (it's not an operator) would indeed do it, if you were using it. You're using rest notation (to gather arguments into an array parameter), but not spread notation (to spread them out when passing them to `console.log`). Here's how you'd use spread:

```
var log = function(...params) {
// Rest -----------^^^
    console.log('[MyPlugin]', ...params);
    // Spread ----------------^^^
};
```

Example:

```js
var log = function(...params) {
// Rest -----------^^^
    console.log('[MyPlugin]', ...params);
    // Spread ---------------^^^
};

log("testing", 1, 2, 3);
```

If you need to support pre-ES2015 environments without transpiling, you can do the same thing with `arguments` and `Function#apply`:

```
var log = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift('[MyPlugin]');
    console.log.apply(console, args);
};
```

Live Example:

```js
var log = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.unshift('[MyPlugin]');
    console.log.apply(console, args);
};

log("testing", 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Wow perfect! The answer was very simple, and thanks for the non-ES2015 too. You were so quick that I can't accept the answer yet!